# Ubuntu 19.04 on 2019 iMac no additional drivers (no WiFi)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, mac

I just installed Ubuntu 19.04 on a new 2019 iMac. I do not have the option of using Ethernet, so I need to have WiFi working. During installation I selected that I wanted to have the proprietary drivers installed, and I also made sure I had an internet connection by tethering my phone's internet connection through USB, however after installation when I go to the Additional Drivers section of Software and Updates, it says "No additional drivers available".

I have tried some of the solutions found on these forums, but none have succeeded so far.

In case it is helpful, I ran the Wireless Info script from [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205)

The output is here: https://pastebin.com/bnp0M1F6

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This wireless devices isn't supported yet by Linux.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6. I guess I am stuck using a WiFi dongle for now.